# How to find location of a source from TDOA

Tags: c#, algorithm

We have 3d system with the source is sending signal and four receivers are receiving it. We know the coordinate location of these four receivers. We have the Time difference of arrival. Could you tell us how to calculate the location of the source.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is actually almost the same as the GPS navigation system. There you have four transmitters at known locations and one receiver in an unknown location, but the principle is exactly the same.

You get a system of four equations:

- |p_1 - p_x| = c * (t + t_1)
- |p_2 - p_x| = c * (t + t_2)
- |p_3 - p_x| = c * (t + t_3)
- |p_4 - p_x| = c * (t + t_4)

where p_x is the position vector of the transmitter and p_n the position vectors of the receivers. t is an unknown (even though it can be solved), t_n are the time differences to each receiver. |v| is the norm of vactor v (length, i.e. distance between stations). c is the speed of light.

There are different ways of solving this group of equations. You might want to have a look at any textbook or web resource of GPS mathematics.

Comment: @ DrV: Thank you. This exactly the problem. I could not find solution. can you share me some links or documents where the mathematical and software solutions are discussed.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the locations of all four receivers, then you can draw circles around them, with each circle having a radius proportional to the time it took the signal to reach that receiver. Where those four circles intersect is the position of the transmitter.

It's a little bit more complicated than that because two circles will intersect in two positions. So you'll need the ability to discard one of the two points from the first circle intersection.

If the circles don't *exactly* intersect at one common point, you'll need some fuzzy matching to get the intersection point.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39561/finding-the-intersecting-points-on-two-circles for information on how to compute circle intersection.

Comment: @ Jim : Thank you Jim for the suggestions. Unfortunately this does not work in our case as we do not have the time take to reach the receiver (TOA). What we have is the Time difference in arrival(TDOA) with respect to the first hit at a receiver.